# Assigning values to array in loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am running a loop:

```
$array = $_POST['d'];

foreach($array as $a){
    print_r($a);
}
```

$array contains the array (the number of array varies) and i get this as a result. I just want to know how i can call these values individually in the loop. for example: $thing = value of methv. i want to call this value in the loop so each time it runs through it will have the next value in the array etc

```
Array ( 
   [1173627548] => Array ( 
     [num] => 1173627548 
     [methv] => dont know 
     [q1] => - 
     [q2] => - 
     [q3] => U 
     [q4] => - 
     [comm] => 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: And how do you usually access array items? (assuming you don't have any loops)

Comment: You mean besides `$a['methv']`?

Comment: If you want to edit a value in your foreach loop you may use `&` in it: `foreach($array as &$a){`

Comment: You asked this exact same question an hour ago.

Comment: Hey @Kolink I thought so too bu I get an undefined error message. fedorqui I tried deleting it but couldnt but i will flag it to mods. HamZa could you please expand on this please thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$array = $_POST['d'];

foreach($array as $a){
   $thing = $a['methv'];
}
```